Manage packages inside a conda environment exclusively throught pip
I would like to use conda as environment manager (in a Windows system) and pip as package manager.
As suggested here, using conda after pip should be avoided; moreover

Only after conda has been used to install as many packages as possible should pip be used to install any remaining software.

If (in a conda environment) I cannot use conda after pip, the only solution is to avoid installing anything with conda and start using pip from the beginning; so I created a totally empty conda environment but, when I install python, conda tries to install many additional packages:
(fem) C:\Users\UP>conda install python
Retrieving notices: ...working... done
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\UP\miniconda3\envs\fem

  added / updated specs:
    - python


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  bzip2              pkgs/main/win-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h2bbff1b_6
  ca-certificates    pkgs/main/win-64::ca-certificates-2024.7.2-haa95532_0
  expat              pkgs/main/win-64::expat-2.6.2-hd77b12b_0
  libffi             pkgs/main/win-64::libffi-3.4.4-hd77b12b_1
  openssl            pkgs/main/win-64::openssl-3.0.14-h827c3e9_0
  pip                pkgs/main/win-64::pip-24.0-py312haa95532_0
  python             pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.12.4-h14ffc60_1
  setuptools         pkgs/main/win-64::setuptools-69.5.1-py312haa95532_0
  sqlite             pkgs/main/win-64::sqlite-3.45.3-h2bbff1b_0
  tk                 pkgs/main/win-64::tk-8.6.14-h0416ee5_0
  tzdata             pkgs/main/noarch::tzdata-2024a-h04d1e81_0
  vc                 pkgs/main/win-64::vc-14.2-h2eaa2aa_4
  vs2015_runtime     pkgs/main/win-64::vs2015_runtime-14.29.30133-h43f2093_4
  wheel              pkgs/main/win-64::wheel-0.43.0-py312haa95532_0
  xz                 pkgs/main/win-64::xz-5.4.6-h8cc25b3_1
  zlib               pkgs/main/win-64::zlib-1.2.13-h8cc25b3_1


Proceed ([y]/n)?

Is it possible to install a bare python in a conda environment (with or without conda), in order to use esclusively pip as package manager inside such conda environment?
In other words I would like to use conda (which is both an environment and package manager) only as environment manager and pip as package manager.

The files installed with conda are not Python modules, they are shared libraries that Python can import as modules; they're parts of the standard library. What you see is bare Python exactly as you want. Any Python installation, conda or not, will include them (at least most of them). The standard library is a part of Python; that makes Python installation less "bare" but anyway that's a minimum you can install.
